# Need to print the lines which are above 200 status code from the access log using shell

Tags: shell

I need to print the lines, whos status code is above 200 from the access log

my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
status=200
while read op ;
do
fun=$(echo $op | sudo tail /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{ print $9}') ;
if [[ $fun -ge $status ]];
then
echo " $(fun) " > /tmp/access.txt
fi
done
```

But still, I am not getting the result.

Comment: What does the input to the loop look like?  Why are you using a loop at all?

Comment: not sure how you are handling your loop iterations but your output to /tmp/access.txt will be overwritten each iteration. You may want to replace > with >>

Comment: Assuming the status is always in column 9, you are probably just looking for `awk '$9 > 200' /var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: Notice the `$(fun)` tries to run `fun` as a command and is substituted by the output of that command (which is unlikely to exist). Probably not the intention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can always expect the status to be in column 9, but you probably just want to do:

```
sudo awk '$9 > status' status=200 /var/log/nginx/access.log > /tmp/access.txt
```

Which is to say, your entire script should be that one line.  There is no need for the while loop at all.

Your title indicates "above 200", but you've used `-ge` in the script, so perhaps you want:

```
sudo awk '$9 >= status' status=200 /var/log/nginx/access.log > /tmp/access.txt
```